# Replacing dynamic number of tags in string with dynamic values - Java

Tags: java, string

I've searched through this website and also google but I couldn't find a specific solution for this problem which I'm facing.

Language: Java

I have a string, let say:

```
String message = "I would like to have <variable>KG of rice and <variable>Litre of Milk. I only have $<variable>, is this sufficient?"
```

Now, user will be having three text fields which will be sorted in order to fill up the variables.

Constraints:

1) User may enter as many  tag in the message

2) The number of text field which will appear is based on number of  tag in the message

Is there anyway where I can replace the original message to this:

"I would like to have {0} KG of rice and {1} Litre of Milk. I only have ${2}, is this sufficient?"

I'm changing  to {X} where X=order number. How to achieve this?

I've thought of using formatter, matcher but I'm getting to dead end all the time. So, can anyone help me on this?

Thank You

Comment: Is the tag fixed? Does the user always type `<variable>` ?

Comment: Does all the variable have to be replaced by the last variable?

If you have {0} & {1} to be replaced and if {0} != {1} and if you have {2} which replaces {0} then it is mathematically impossible to find out the value of two. If you have two unknowns then you need at-least 2 equations to resolve it.

Comment: Why don't you just use string concatenation?

Comment: @flup - user will always use <variable>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what you want to achieve, but if I understand the exact question correctly and you wish to replace the string `<variable>` in the user's input with `{0}`, `{1}`, `{2}` successively then I think this is the answer:

You can use a `Matcher` to match all occurrences of `<variable>`, and then iterate over the matches and use [appendReplacement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement%28java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String%29) to replace them by `{0}`, `{1}`, `{2}`, etc.

So

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("<variable>").matcher(input);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
for( int i = 0; m.find(); i++){
    m.appendReplacement(sb, "{"+i+"}");
}
m.appendTail(sb);
```

Comment: Yes, this would solve my first issue. I'll put this as answer.

Answer (score 5):

Try this one.

```
String s = java.text.MessageFormat.format("I would like to have {0} KG of rice and {1} Litre of Milk. I only have ${2}, is this sufficient?",new String[]{"100","5","50"});
System.out.println(s);
```

**Output**

I would like to have 100 KG of rice and 5 Litre of Milk. I only have $50, is this sufficient?

Answer (score 2):

String.format is handy instead of loops. Take a look at below:

```
String mesage = "I would like to have %d KG of rice and %d Litre of Milk. I only have $ %d is this sufficient?";
System.out.println(String.format(mesage, 5, 1, 10));
System.out.println(String.format(mesage, 10, 2, 50));
```

Refer https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-format for different format specifiers: %d %s etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
String mesage = "I would like to have " + kg + 
"KG of rice and " + litre + "Litre of Milk. I only have $" + dollor + " 
is this sufficient?";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
int i = 0;
while(message.contains("<variable>")) {
    message = message.replaceFirst("<variable>", "{" + i + "}");
    i++;
}
```

This will result in:

```
I would like to have {0}KG of rice and {1}Litre of Milk. I only have ${2}, is this sufficient?
```

Comment: Yes I know, this is the first I could think of, it should illustrate the basic idea of solving the problem. @flup's solution looks much better! (Working on a String inside a loop is generally a bad idea)